# Tools to create the file necessary to integrate an application with AppleScript

Tags: cocoa, applescript

Are there any tools that allow to create the necessary files required to add the support for AppleScript in an application?

I am looking for a tool that simplifies the task, possibility one that requires me to just give a description of the involved classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sdef Editor](http://shadowlab.org/softwares/sdefeditor.php).

Comment: Does Sdef supports Mac OS X 10.6, or does not Snow Leopard introduce new features? Sdef doesn't seem to check the type I use in the definition; could not there any conflict that I would not notice?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6 supports sdef files authored for older versions of Mac OS X. As far as I know, they didn't add a completely new format and call it “sdef” just like the previous one. As for new features: I have no idea. Check the sdef manpage (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sdef.5.html ). Even if they did, that doesn't mean Sdef Editor won't work, even if it doesn't provide the new features yet.

Comment: Looking at the manpage, they report only changes in Mac OS X 10.5; I guess that means Snow Leopard didn't introduce any changes.  
Thanks for your reply (and your answer).